# Get the last two weeks SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wonder if there is a way to get the last two weeks and their amounts in SQL , I explain:

The following query brings me the last two weeks with their quantities of a product in this way :

```
SELECT pr_products.product,
       WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date) AS week, 
       SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS quantity
       FROM pf_harvest
       INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
       WHERE pf_harvest.date BETWEEN '2016-08-15' AND '2016-08-28'
       AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1
       AND pf_harvest.id_product = 1
       GROUP BY product, WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date);
```

The result I get is the following:

```
-------------------------------------
product     |    week  |   quantity |
-------------------------------------
ROSA PINK   |    33    |    1076000 |
-------------------------------------
ROSA PINK   |    34    |    1094025 |
-------------------------------------
```

That is fine, the problem is that I want the query result left me something like this:

```
-------------------------------------
product     |    week1 |   week2    |
-------------------------------------
ROSA PINK   |  1076000 |    1094025 |
-------------------------------------
```

This is to obtain the quantities of both week 33 and the 34 grouped in a single product , I don´t know if it is possible do it this way, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use conditional aggergation. each column is aggregating only its week. so one query with one pass will get you both aggregations.

```
SELECT pr_products.product,
       SUM(case when WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date)=43 then pf_harvest.quantity end) week1, 
       SUM(case when WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date)=44 then pf_harvest.quantity end) week2
FROM pf_harvest
   INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
WHERE pf_harvest.date BETWEEN '2016-08-15' AND '2016-08-28'
 AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1
 AND pf_harvest.id_product = 1
GROUP BY product
```

Comment: Thtat´s ok, but in this case may be different weeks

Comment: sorry I didn't understand you. I do query different weeks (43 into week1 column, and 44 into week2 column). just change the week numbers and date range.

Comment: yes, but I can not set the week in each case because the two weeks are obtained from the current date

Comment: you can use `WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE())` and `WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE())-1`

Answer (score 1):

to achieve something like that Union Select is used

```
    SELECT pr_products.product,

       SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS week1
       FROM pf_harvest
       INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
       WHERE pf_harvest.date BETWEEN '2016-08-15' AND '2016-08-21'
       AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1
       AND pf_harvest.id_product = 1
       GROUP BY product, WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date);
UNION
    SELECT 
       SUM(pf_harvest.quantity) AS week2
       FROM pf_harvest
       INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = pf_harvest.id_product
       WHERE pf_harvest.date BETWEEN '2016-08-21' AND '2016-08-28'
       AND pf_harvest.id_tenant = 1
       AND pf_harvest.id_product = 1
       GROUP BY product, WEEKOFYEAR(pf_harvest.date);
```

The first select gets data for the week 1 and the second gets data for week 2.

for more info about union you can read on [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Comment: I try this, but only give me the first week or how can I obtain the second week too?

Comment: can you please provide the structure of the two tables

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is not the best way but you can use an offset merge to bring it in. If memory serves, this should label the fields as product|week|week(1)|week(2)|....

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that:

```
SELECT pr_products.product,
       SUM(h1.quantity) AS Week1,
       SUM(h2.quantity) AS Week2
       FROM pr_product
       LEFT JOIN pf_harvest h1 ON pr_products.id = h1.id_product ,
       LEFT JOIN pf_harvest h2 ON pr_products.id = h2.id_product
       WHERE 
       ( h1.date BETWEEN '2016-08-15' AND '2016-08-21'
       AND h1.id_tenant = 1
       AND h1.id_product = 1 )  
    OR
       ( h2.date BETWEEN '2016-08-22' AND '2016-08-28'
       AND h2.id_tenant = 1
       AND h2.id_product = 1 )  
       GROUP BY product ;
```